# Using sklearn One-Hot-Encoding object to transform subset of features

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I've fit a sklearn one-hot-encoding object on my development data to create dummy variables in python. I need to transform my scoring data (post implementation) accordingly using this one-hot-encoder object. But my problem is that the scoring data has only the model variables, as opposed to all variables in the development data. Hence the one-hot-encoding fails as the object expects all variables. How can I transform the scoring data with limited number of variables using the one-hot-encode object?

Comment: Could you please give us an example of your data that you have one-hot-encoded? It is very difficult to help you without that. You should have the same number of categorical inputs in the developmental data as in the scoring data.

Comment: Let's suppose the development data has 4 columns - ['age', 'city', 'education', 'job']. I fit an one-hot-encoder object on these 4 columns. Now, let's also suppose that only age and city comes as significant in the model.

Post implementation, I get only these model vars - ['age', 'city']. How do I encode these two vars using the same one-hot-encoding object?

Comment: The One Hot Encoder does not really fit anything, it is however using the API of scikit and you cannot use it on data that has a different shape. You can either fit a specific one hot encoder on only the variables available in the scoring data or use a different transformation like [pd.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)

Comment: @projjwal Either you remove the categories from your dev data that is not available later or you fill the scoring data with a default value for missing values. I would go with the first as it seems you are missing datapoints in a majority of you "true" data if that is the case.

Comment: @Luis Blanche: Thanks much. pd.get_dummies works perfectly in my case. :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.